# Are Blogger draft posts synced between the computer and the phone?

Tags: blogger, synchronization

I blog a lot, and quite often I blog about things while on the go using the Blogger android application that is available on Google Play.

Sometimes, I write posts on my phone, but due to the limited capabilities that it has in the editor, I prefer to just write the blog post directly in the computer and publish from there.

The question now is: Can I save blog posts as draft on my phone so that I can pick up from where I left off on the computer by opening the same draft without having to type everything again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was quite surprised no one had an answer for this simple question (perhaps its too simple to be constructive). Anyway, Blogger syncs draft posts between the phone and the computer, so that you always have access to the same draft regardless of what system you use.

Comment: It made you earn a badge though...;-)

Comment: Well i just published a post written on my laptop and i cannot see it when i open my blog on my phone